# Execute a code when returning form safari (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I use the facebook sdk in my app. The facebook sdk takes the user to a safari facebook login. Once the facebook login is done the user is taken back to the app and i want to write a set of code to get the access token and proceed with the operation. But where should this code to be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly set up the callback URL of your app (something like `fb19374518456`, where the long number is the Facebook app ID), then Facebook will redirect you from Safari back to the app. In this case, you can implement the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sApp annotation:(id)ann
```

method and pass the URL you get to the facebook SDK - it will then parse the URL and obtain the access token and expiration date from it.